# Certificate Validation and Revocation (CRL) X509 disable in java code

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509

Does anyone know how to disable checking Certificate Validation and Revocation (CRL) X509 for certain certificate?
I have default turn ON checking Certificate Validation and Revocation in system and can not disable that, because it could affect other certificates:

> -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=true

But for one certain X509 cert I want to turn off validation in java code.